# Keep the timestamp in SVN via commandline

Tags: datetime, svn, version-control, timestamp

we want to use `svn update --config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes` instead of local changing the config-file. However the command results in `svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes'`. Moreover, changing the `servers-config` with `svn update --config-option servers:global:http-proxy-port=2`(only as further example) isn't possible, too.

We use svn 1.9.6 and Win7.

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do a clean checkout first:

```
svn checkout --config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes <repo-url>
```

and then every time you update:

```
svn update --config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes
```